# Delphi: Save Multiline Strings to File

Tags: delphi, tstringlist

Good evening all.

I have a StringList and each record contains a multi-line string.

MyStringList [0]:

```
<li>
  Test1
</li>
```

MyStringList [1]:

```
<a href="#">
  <b>      
    Test2
  </b>
</a>
```

etc.

How can I save and load those strings to a file (text, ini, binary, record, savetofile, etc.) ? The main issue is than I can save it to a text file, but when reading back, each line is considered a new record while there are 3 lines for the first record, 5 lines for the second and so on.

What do you suggest for a process to save and load those strings ?

Comment: If you save it as a text file then there's no chance of recovering the information.

Comment: Your `MyStringList[0]` is a single line string. `<li>` does not cause a line break; `<li>Test1</li>` in a single line is totally valid HTML. If you write it with line breaks to a file, it will be read back as separate lines. If you've stored `<li>`line break`   Test1`line break`</li>`, then it's not a single line string.

Comment: @Ken I take it that the strings in the string list contain linebreaks

Comment: Indeed, it does contain linebreaks: '<li> #10#13 Test1 #10#13 </li>'

Comment: Are you prepared to save a separate file which says where to put the linebreaks?

Comment: You mean a separate file for each record ? Well, I have a lot records (3000+) in the StringList, some records contain only a line, while other may contain 200. It would be an option to make 3000+ files (one for each record) but that seems not very "friendly"

Comment: I could try to convert each #10#13 to something else (as #TOTO#) and save the stringlist using SaveToFile. I could probably load it and convert each #TOTO# back to #10#13. I may give that a try.

Comment: No, I meant one file. With a map in effect. Anyway, if you can use a binary approach, do so.

Comment: Thanks David for the suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you save it to a `.txt` file, you lose the ability to re-load it correctly, since you don't know if a give line break was originally embedded in a string, or separates two strings.

If you save it to another textual format, like `.ini`, you can escape/unescape the line breaks as needed, eg:

```
function Encode(const S: String): String;
begin
  Result := StringReplace(S, '<', '<<', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, #13#10, '<CRLF>', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, #13, '<CR>', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, #10, '<LF>', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;

Ini := TIniFile.Create(...);
try
  Ini.WriteInteger('section', 'count', MyStringList.Count);
  for I := 0 to MyStringList.Count-1 do
    Ini.WriteString('section', IntToStr(I), Encode(MyStringList[I]);
finally
  Ini.Free;
end;
```

```
function Decode(const S: String): String;
begin
  Result := StringReplace(S, '<LF>', #10, [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, '<CR>', #13, [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, '<CRLF>', #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result, '<<', '<', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

end;

```
Ini := TIniFile.Create(...);
try
  Count := Ini.ReadInteger('section', 'count', 0);
  for I := 0 to Count-1 do
    MyStringList.Add(Decode(Ini.ReadString('section', IntToStr(I), ''));
finally
  Ini.Free;
end;
```

If you save it to a binary format, you can preserve the line breaks as-is, eg:

```
procedure WriteIntegerToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: Integer);
begin
  Stream.WriteBuffer(Value, SizeOf(Integer));
end;

procedure WriteStringToStream(Stream: TStream; const Value: String);
var
  U: UTF8String;
  Count: Integer;
begin
  U := UTF8String(Value); // or UTF8Encode(Value) prior to D2009
  Count := Length(U);
  WriteIntegerToStream(Stream, Count);
  if Count > 0 then
    Stream.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(U)^, Count * SizeOf(AnsiChar));
end;

Strm := TFileStream.Create(..., fmCreate);
try
  WriteIntegerToStream(Stream, MyStringList.Count);
  for I := 0 to MyStringList.Count-1 do
    WriteStringToStream(Stream, MyStringList[I]);
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

```
function ReadIntegerFromStream(Stream: TStream): Integer;
begin
  Stream.ReadBuffer(Result, SizeOf(Integer));
end;

function ReadStringFromStream(Stream: TStream): String;
var
  Count: Integer;
  U: UTF8String;
begin
  Count := ReadIntegerFromStream(Stream);
  if Count > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(U, Count);
    Stream.ReadBuffer(PAnsiChar(U)^, Count * SizeOf(AnsiChar));
    Result := String(U); // or UTF8Decode(U) prior to D2009
  end else
    Result := '';
end;

Stream := TFileStream.Create(..., fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
try
  Count := ReadIntegerFromStream(Stream);
  for I := 0 to Count-1 do
    MyStringList.Add(ReadStringFromStream(Stream));
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Your Binary sample seems to be good. I will give it a try. Many thanks

Comment: Then you'd need to escape any instances of `<CRLF>`. Binary is much cleaner.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Or at least escape `<` characters since they are being reserved for escaping.